# Delete seaborn boxplot y label on pyplot subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Can't delete ylabels on every plot. Can you please give me a hint.**

I have been able to plot several seaborn boxplots on a pyplot subplot, but I'm not able to get rid of the y labels.

```
fig, axes= plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(10,10))
sb.boxplot(y= data['Coordenadas_Punto_X' ], ax=axes[0,0]).set_title('longitude')
sb.boxplot(y= data['Coordenadas_Punto_Y' ], ax=axes[0,1]).set_title('latitude')
sb.boxplot(y= data['rvi' ], ax=axes[0,2]).set_title('rvi')
sb.boxplot(y= data['ndvi' ], ax=axes[0,3]).set_title('ndvi')
sb.boxplot(y= data['evi' ], ax=axes[1,0]).set_title('evi')
sb.boxplot(y= data['evi2' ], ax=axes[1,1]).set_title('evi2')
sb.boxplot(y= data['lswi' ], ax=axes[1,2]).set_title('lswi')
sb.boxplot(y= data['Unidades o Hectáreas Financiadas' ], ax=axes[1,3]).set_title('Unidades o has Financiadas')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSivO.png)

Comment: You can use `plt.setp(axes, ylabel="")` to set the labels to an empty string. (Also note that `squeeze=False` in `plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, squeeze=False)` will create a 2D array of axes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove each `Boxplot` y label like below.

#### Solution 1

```py
plt.setp(axes, ylabel="")
```

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'Coordenadas_Punto_X': [1, 2], 'Coordenadas_Punto_Y': [3, 4]})

fig, axes= plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(4,4))
sb.boxplot(y= data['Coordenadas_Punto_X' ], ax=axes[0]).set_title('longitude')
sb.boxplot(y= data['Coordenadas_Punto_Y' ], ax=axes[1]).set_title('latitude')
plt.setp(axes, ylabel="")
fig.tight_layout()
```

#### Solution 2

```py
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.set_ylabel('')
```

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'Coordenadas_Punto_X': [1, 2], 'Coordenadas_Punto_Y': [3, 4]})

fig, axes= plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(4,4))
sb.boxplot(y= data['Coordenadas_Punto_X' ], ax=axes[0]).set_title('longitude')
sb.boxplot(y= data['Coordenadas_Punto_Y' ], ax=axes[1]).set_title('latitude')

for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    
fig.tight_layout()
```

Each solution get same result.

[image]